# Video streaming with Kotlin and Ktor

Tags: postgresql, kotlin, ktor, minio

I'm writing a backend application in Kotlin+Ktor. The task is that with an html form the user submits a video that needs to be saved in MinIO. Then, at the user’s request, you need to get this video from the storage and start streaming it on an html page.
But I encountered a problem when retrieving videos from the storage (videos with chunks).
The following error appears:

```
DEBUG Application - 206 Partial Content: GET - /video/21e57ab6-3275-47e0-9e27-8b522d7f21a9. Exception class io.ktor.util.cio.ChannelWriteException: Cannot write to a channel
    Caused by: [CIRCULAR REFERENCE: io.ktor.util.cio.ChannelWriteException: Cannot write to a channel]Caused by: java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
```

the error occurs in Handler in the line

```
output.write(chunkWithMetadata.chunk)
```

Handler code:

```
             get("/{uuid}") {
                    val uuid = UUID.fromString(call.parameters["uuid"])
                    val range = call.request.headers["Range"]
        
                    val parsedRange = Range.parseHttpRangeString(range, defaultChunkSize)
                    val chunkWithMetadata = videoService.fetchChunk(uuid, parsedRange)
        
                    call.response.header("Content-Type",         chunkWithMetadata.metadata.`httpContentType`)
                    call.response.header("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
                    call.response.header(
                        "Content-Length",
                        calculateContentLengthHeader(parsedRange,   chunkWithMetadata.metadata.size)
                    )
                    call.response.header(
                        "Content-Range",
                        constructContentRangeHeader(parsedRange, chunkWithMetadata.metadata.size)
                    )
        
                    call.respondOutputStream(
                        status = HttpStatusCode.PartialContent,
                        contentType = ContentType(
                            contentType = chunkWithMetadata.metadata.httpContentType,
                            contentSubtype = chunkWithMetadata.metadata.httpContentType
                        ),
                        contentLength = calculateContentLengthHeader(parsedRange, chunkWithMetadata.metadata.size).toLong(),
                    ) {
                        val output = this
                        output.write(chunkWithMetadata.chunk)
                    }
                }
```

Service code:

```
        override suspend fun fetchChunk(uuid: UUID, range: Range): ChunkWithMetadata {
            val fileMetadata = fileMetadataDAOFacade.findById(uuid)
            return ChunkWithMetadata(fileMetadata!!, readChunk(uuid, range, fileMetadata.size))
        }
    
        private fun readChunk(uuid: UUID, range: Range, fileSize: Long): ByteArray {
            val startPosition = range.getRangeStart()
            val endPosition = range.getRangeEnd(fileSize)
            val chunkSize = (endPosition - startPosition + 1)
    
            try {
                storageService.getInputStream(uuid, startPosition, chunkSize).use { inputStream ->
                    return inputStream.readAllBytes()
                }
            } catch (exception: Exception) {
                throw StorageException(exception)
            }
        }
    
        data class ChunkWithMetadata(
            val metadata: FileMetadataEntity,
            val chunk: ByteArray
        )
```

Please tell me what could be the problem

The ultimate goal is for a video to be launched at a specific URL in the browser. At the moment, only the form is displayed, but the video itself is not loading.

The problem is that I don't know which response is best to return and how to add headers to the response

Comment: If you write a ByteArray to the response, try using the `call.respondBytes` method.

Comment: @AlekseiTirman I did this, the error went away, but the video still did not load. Loading takes forever